# Puppeteer needs to restart server for each scrape

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer, nestjs

I'm **scraping** a website with Puppeteer using a Nest.js [module](https://github.com/tinovyatkin/nest-puppeteer).

The **scraping** works the first time I call the GET method, but it won't scrape again after that. Which means I have to **restart** the server each for each **scraping**, which isn't ideal.

**Scraping** code (Simplified):

```js
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(@InjectBrowser() private readonly browser: Browser) {}

  async getFoodoraRestaurantMenus(url: string): Promise<string> {
    console.log("Calling method");
    const page = await this.browser.newPage();
    console.log('Never gets here the second time');

    await page.goto(url);

    const content = await page.evaluate(() => {});

    await this.browser.close();

    return JSON.stringify(content, null, 4);
  }
}
```

The second time I call `getFoodoraRestaurantMenus` I never get to the second console log, so a new page is never opened. I'm unsure if I need to do something more than `browser.close()`, that was all I could find.

I have no idea why I need to restart the server each time I want to perform a scrape. All help I can get is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: ` await this.browser.close();` you are closing browser then you are trying to call it again `this.browser.newPage();` ... simply don't close it (or relaunch it), close a tab :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to free the memory and reuse the same browser, you could try only closing the page instead of the browser:

```
await page.close();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! All examples I saw included `await browser.close()`. I thought it was a requirement haha